# How to store big values in shell script variable

Tags: bash, shell, busybox, ash

When I store big values in variable busybox shell script and print, it prints -ve values.
I know shell doesn't have variable type but then how do I avoid this folding back to -ve values ?
I used below command commands in shell and it prints -ve value.

```
# let b=3841982464
# echo $b
-452984832
```

Any suggestion/pointer ?

EDIT:
Answer suggested by agilob works for my original question but my actual problem is, I was last to go to end of disk - 17kb So I used command as follows

```
# b=$(($(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk0) - $((17*1024))))
# echo $b
-453002240
```

So still value is printed -ve :(, using expr also gives weird result as follows

```
# b=`expr $(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk0) - 17408`
# echo $b
2147466239
```

**Answer to actual problem**
so original question was answered by agilob so I accepted that answer. And actual problem I could solve as follows,

```
# b=$(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk0)
# echo $b
3841982464
# echo "$b 17408 - p" | dc
3841965056
```

**AWK way**

I tried doing it in awk way as user1934428 suggested, it can be done as follows,

```
# echo "$(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk0) 17408" | awk '{ printf "%.0f", $1 - $2}'
3841965056#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just:

```
b=3841982464
echo $b
   => 3841982464
```

Comment: Omg i thought it is same as `let b=3841982464`. Thank you. Btw What is a difference?

Comment: okay above solution works. But if i used it as follows ` b=$(($(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk0) - $((17*1024))))` it prints `# echo $b`
`-453002240`, do u suggest to use expr?

Comment: `let` evaluates expression, let a=1-1; echo $a; will print 0. please accept answer if you dont mind ;)

Comment: Actually I want to evaluate the expression and the same time i don't want values to be folded.

Comment: I'm on windows right now, I'll help you with that when I'm at home on linux, try changing $(( to other cmd executors like `` or eval(?)

Comment: Do you suggest using dc ? i don't have bc in busybox.

Comment: As suggested below, you can try with ruby -e '`blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk0` - 1740'; I'm not sure about the syntax, but it should be pretty easy to use. It uses ruby interpreter to exec command and subtract number from returned value.

Comment: If you don't have ruby on that machine, try other examples from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to do arithmetic with "arbitrary long integers". This is not built into bash (which uses 8 byte integer).

I would store the numbers in just normal environment variables and use other programming languages (for instance Ruby) to process them.

Comment: Thank you for reply @user1934428, i don't have ruby in my board. i could solve it with `dc`

Comment: It's just an example. There are many choices. The reason why I possibly would not do it with dc / bc is because  scripts with such numeric requirements are sometimes easier to solve, when they are completely implemented in a different language than shell. I occasionally start with a shell script, using Ruby or Perl or Awk for solving simple subtasks, and over time, I take out more and more functionality from the script and into the programming language of choice ;-)

Comment: I agree with you on the moving script to programming language is better Idea. Just out of curiosity do you move small functionality of script to small programs ? Do you use mix of both them then ?

Comment: I do mix them, because I enjoy using the tool which works best for the data at hand. However, I mix them only if the tasks can be clearly separated, because otherwise passing the information back and forth can be a pain. Most of the time, I have a general driver program often used in the Z-Shell, which then invokes for sub-tasks programs written in other languages. Once I'm within, say, Perl or Ruby, I rarely feel the temptation to invoke a shell script for performing a sub-task, unless this sub-task can be seen as independent, generally useful tool.

Comment: I did it in awk way also, that looks much familiar and readable to others also, if they look at my script, i am going to use that.